# Line integral over vector fields

Tags: partial-differential-equations, vector-analysis, line-integrals

Evaluate the line integral $\oint_
CH\cdot n\mathrm{d}s$
through the sum of the integrals over the sides
of :
$$∮
_
H · n\mathrm{d} =
∫
_{1}
H · n\mathrm{d} +
∫
_{2}
H · n\mathrm{d} +
∫
_{3}H · n  +
∫
_{4}
H · n\mathrm{d}$$
where 1, 2, 3 and 4 are the four sides of .
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/KAEUp.png)

The link has the diagram needed. Please help. I have used a variant of green's theorem and used $\mathrm{d}s = \mathrm{d}x~\hat{\mathrm{i}} + \mathrm{d}y~\hat{\mathrm{j}}$ which then allows me to use $n\mathrm{d}s  = \mathrm{d}y~\hat{\mathrm{i}} - \mathrm{d}x~\hat{\mathrm{j}}$. After this working out the equation of each line allows me to substitute and do the integration with respect to $\mathrm{d}x$. I have done this and got 4 as my answer but when I do the double integral to check my answers don't match. $H = x~\hat{\mathrm{i}}+y~\hat{\mathrm{j}}$

Comment: What have you tried?

Comment: I have tried using a variant of green's theorem but when I do the double integral to check the answers don't match.

Comment: I got 4 as the answer

Comment: I understand but your post will most likely get closed as is. You must add details on your attempt in the body of your question and tell where you are stuck - not in comments but in your question. Once you do that, I will be able to provide help.

Comment: I have edited the question

Comment: But you have not mentioned the value of the vector field, $H$.

Comment: sorry yea I have added it

Answer (score 1):

You have made a mistake in your line integral somewhere as the sum should be zero and not $4$.

Please note that if the vector field is $\vec H = (x,y)$,
$Q_x = P_y = 0$ where $P = x, Q = y$.

So the line integral over a closed curve will be zero.

Line integral $\displaystyle = \oint_C (Q_x - P_y) \ dA = 0$

Line integral over $S2$ in anticlockwise direction,

$r(t) = (1,2) + (0-1, 1-2)t = (1-t,2-t), 0 \leq t \leq 1$

Line integral over $S2 = \displaystyle \int_0^1 (1-t,2-t) \cdot (-1,-1) \ dt = - 2$

Line integral over $S4$ in anticlockwise direction,

$r(t) = (1,0) + (2-1, 1-0)t = (1+t,t), 0 \leq t \leq 1$

Line integral over $S4 = \displaystyle \int_0^1 (1+t,t) \cdot (1,1) \ dt = 2$

So the sum over $S2$ and $S4$ is zero. Also line integral along $S1$ and $S3$ is zero. Please do the working and check.

Comment: thank you I will redo my working and check

Comment: Could you please explain in more detail how you worked out line integral of S2

Comment: It is similar to $S4$. The starting point of $S2$ is $(1,2)$ and endpoint is $(0,1)$. So you subtract starting point position vector from endpoint and that gives you direction vector. So the points on the line are given by the position vector of starting point and  direction vector.